# Meta data issue wcf rest

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, rest

So trying to create a rest service but I keep getting an error:

[image]

If I try to run it in a browser I get : `The type 'WcfService2.Service1', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive could not be found.`

```
namespace WcfService2
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public class HelloWorldService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "")]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello world!";
        }
    }
}

namespace WcfService2
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in code, svc and config file together.

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WebHttpBinding binding = new WebHttpBinding();
            WebServiceHost host =
            new WebServiceHost(typeof(HelloWorldService));
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(HelloWorldService),
            binding,
            "http://localhost:8000/Hello");
            host.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Hello world service");
            Console.WriteLine("Press <RETURN> to end service");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're defining a **REST-style** WCF service using the `WebHttpBinding`.

The WCF Test Client is only usable for **SOAP** services - not for REST services. REST services can be tested using your regular browser, or tools like Fiddler.

The error message you're getting would almost indicate that you have a `*.svc` lying around somewhere, too, that gets in your way. Is that the case?

Comment: Yeah but if I right click and view in browser I get The type 'WcfService2.Service1', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive could not be found.

Comment: @Garrith: again - you cannot do that (*View in browser*) - that's for **SOAP** services. You need to **actually run your console app** so that the correct service host and the correct addresses get activated ....

Comment: I dont have a console app for this?

Comment: @Garrith: sure you do! That's the `class program { ... static void Main(......) ` ...... or maybe it's a WInforms app - you definitely have an **application** here that instantiates the proper service host - that app **must be running** for you to connect to your WCF service